# Debug apache arrow using R

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow

I am rather new to apache arrow hence this may be an easy question. I've tried to find information online without success. I have a algorithm I'm using to simulate data as well as perform calculations. Since I'm trying to simulate large data sets, I've looking into apache arrow. The problem I have is that R get stuck at a specific part of a function and I can't understand why. When it get stuck and I press the red stop buttom at the top right cornor of the consol I get the error:

"R is not responding to your request to interrupt the processing so to stop the current operation you may need to terminate R entirely.

Terminating R will cause you R session to immediately abort. Active computations will be interrupted and unsaved source file changes and workspace objects will be discarded.

Do you want to terminate R now?

This is troublesome since I want to run the algorithm for several hours. Sometimes the problem occues after just a few iterations and sometime after a few hundred iterations.

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

N<-500000
sample <- data.frame(id = 1:N,
                     x = runif(N,0,1),
                     y1 = rnorm(N,8,3),
                     y2 = rnorm(N,15,3),
                     poststratum = round(runif(N,0,4)),
                     SRS = round(runif(N,0,1)),
                     SRS_R_y1 = round(runif(N,0,1)),
                     SRS_R_y2 =round(runif(N,0,1)))
arrow::write_dataset(sample, paste0("samples/test.pq"))



samples <- arrow::open_dataset(list.files(paste0("samples/test.pq"), full.names = TRUE))

stratum_function <- function(data_in, method, y, x){
  print(x)
  print("1")
  # Calculate big in each stratum
  f1 <- data_in %>% group_by(poststratum) %>% summarise(N_s = n()) 
  print("2")
  # Calculate number of respondants in each stratum
  f2 <- data_in %>% 
    filter(.data[[paste0(method, "_", y)]] == 1) %>% 
    group_by(poststratum) %>% 
    summarise(n_s = n()) 
  print("3")
  # Join two privious parquets together
  f3 <- left_join(f1,f2 ,by = "poststratum")
  print("4")
  gc()
  # Calculate weights based on post stratification method
  f4 <- f3 %>% mutate(w_s = N_s / n_s, 
                      W_SQ_S_s = (N_s / n_s)*(N_s / n_s)) 
  print("5")
  
  f5 <- f4 %>% collect() 
  print("6")
}

lapply(1:10000, FUN=function(x){stratum_function(samples,"SRS_R", "y1", x)})
```

This is a the part of the code that get stuck. It always get stuck after "5" is printed. I just did three simulations and got to x = 434, x = 332 and x = 175. So it is no consistent pattern. I have monitored the CPU and memory and they never go over max 60% capacity.

```
dplyr version: 1.1.2
arrow version 11.0.0.3

RStudio 2023.06.1+524 "Mountain Hydrangea" Release (547dcf861cac0253a8abb52c135e44e02ba407a1, 2023-07-07) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.06.1+524 Chrome/110.0.5481.208 Electron/23.3.0 Safari/537.36


> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

Comment: Are you able to provide sample data? Even if it's a small frame using `arrow::arrow_table`, it'll help to reproduce the problem with smaller data. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply r2evens. I've edited the post to include information about the dataset. I run the alforithm at different sizez of N, there is no clear pattern to when it start to crash but generally it seems to work without problem when N is around100000 but when I get to 200k or 300k starts to crash. Sometimes I can perform the algorithm 10-20 times only at N=300k, sometimes 100-300 times at N=300k before it crash. I have the results gradually, and when I restart the algorithm and run it again at the point of crashing it always work fine until the next crash 10-400 iterations later

Comment: How are you calling your function when it fails? (What are your other arguments?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @r2evens. I've added the prior commands that leads up to this function. I've added ... to the part where other things are exceuted which are not directly related to this and that doesn't cause a problem. The starnge thing is that I use the collect() function at several other part of the algorithm without any problems, it is always at this specific point it crash.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to troubleshoot from my end. I just created a 500K-row dataset generated randomly, using the same class (numeric/integer), same range (literally sampled between min/max for each column), etc. I then created the three functions as-is, called `raw_statistics(samples)`, and it completed in a few seconds. Not sure what is different. Look for `NA`, `NaN`, `Inf`, or negative/zero values where you don't expect them. Look for very large or very small values where you don't expect them.

Comment: Hi again r2evens. I really appreciate that you try to help. My initial though was that this might have been a know problem and therefore I formulated the question in such a way. I realize now that this was the wrong approach. I've reformulated the question now and added new code which just be more or less just copy paste.

Comment: That's a better approach. I did something very similar to that, preferring `sample(0:1)` to `round(runif(0,1))`, I think that did nothing. I did not have ranges as far as you did, so it's possible that that introduces some complexity? If I can, I'll check later (busy atm).

Comment: Again, thank you so much for taking the time. It is no rush but I really want to understand why this happens since I see so much value in understanding the package. Ye sample(0:1) definitely looks better.

Comment: I ran your code and it completed without error. :-( I ran it on: R-4.2.3, dplyr-1.1.2, arrow-13.0.0 ... perhaps update arrow?

Comment: I updated both R and arrow and it has now been running without problem for 30 minutes which it hasn't done before. Thank you so much for the help!